# How to flush the console buffer?

Tags: c, getchar

i have some code that run repetedly :

> printf("do you want to continue? Y/N: \n");
>   keepplaying = getchar();

in the next my code is running it doesnt wait for input.
i found out that getchar in the seconed time use '\n' as the charcter.
im gussing this is due to some buffer the sdio has, so it save the last input which was "Y\n" or "N\n".

my Q is, how do i flush the buffer before using the getchar, which will make getchar wait for my answer?

Comment: Are you using C or C++? They're not the same language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flushing an input stream causes undefined behaviour.

> int fflush(FILE *ostream);
>
> ostream points to an output stream or
>   an update stream in which the most
>   recent operation was not input, the
>   fflush function causes any unwritten
>   data for that stream to be delivered
>   to the host environment to be written
>   to the file; otherwise, the behavior
>   is undefined.

To properly flush the input stream do something like the following:

```
int main(void)
{
  int   ch;
  char  buf[BUFSIZ];

  puts("Flushing input");

  while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);

  printf ("Enter some text: ");

  if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin))
  {
    printf ("You entered: %s", buf);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

See [Why fflush(stdin) is wrong](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1052863818&id=1043284351) and [Flush the input buffer](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044873249&id=1043284392).

Comment: thats what i did, i just wanted to know if there is an easier way

Comment: The easier way is to use fflush which may not work in all environment and in all situation.

Comment: You can use the libraries specific to your platform to handle user input (WIN32, GTK, ncurses, etc.) which will hide these kind of  details from you.

Answer (score 1):

use fflush() and flushall() before printf

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `flushall` is not POSIX. In order to flush a console buffer in a standard way, you can simply use the command:

```
fflush(NULL);
```

This topic seems to be a bit old but I hope this can still help the others.