# Whats wrong with getchar in C, please?

Tags: c, struct

I wrote this code to do some algebra with imaginary numbers using structs but when i run it, i get this [image]

What am i doing wrong i tried all the different ways to get a char , i am puzzled!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct complex { float Rez, Imz; }; 

int main( )
{
    char operand;
struct complex z1, z2;
printf("give the Real part of the first imaginary number z1:\n");
scanf( "%f", &z1.Rez ); 
printf("zreal=%f",z1.Rez);
printf("give the Imaginary part of the first imaginary number z1: \n");
scanf( "%f", &z1.Imz );     
printf("give the Real part of the second imaginary number z2: \n");
scanf( "%f", &z2.Rez ); 
printf("give the Imaginary part of the second imaginary number z2: \n");
scanf( "%f", &z2.Imz ); 
do
{
    printf("Give + for ADD\nGive * for MULTIPLICATION\nGive - for SUBTRACTION\nGive / for DIVISION\n");
    operand=getchar();
    if (operand!='+' || operand!='-' || operand!='*' || operand!='/')
        printf("Wrong operation.Try again.\n");
}while(operand!='+' || operand!='-' || operand!='*' || operand!='/');

if(operand=='+')
{
    printf("\nYou have chosen to add the numbers.\nThe result of the ADD is the inaginary number\n imz=(%f+%f) +(%f+%f)",z1.Rez,z2.Rez,z1.Imz,z2.Imz);  
}
if(operand=='-')
{

}
if(operand=='*')
{

}
if(operand=='/')
{

}
system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Please any suggestions?Iam stuck!

Comment: It's impressing how none of you has come to the idea to use a debugger to inspect the value of `operand` after the `getchar` call for three hours... ;)

Comment: @mafso certainly `getchar()` is returning `'\n'`.  Better to use with `scanf(" %c", &operand)` and get the `||` vs. `&&` right.

Answer (score 4):

`if (operand!='+' || operand!='-' || operand!='*' || operand!='/')`

This statement is always true, because at most one of the four conditions can be false.

you should have wrote this :

`if (operand!='+' && operand!='-' && operand!='*' && operand!='/')`

same mistake for the `while` loop : always true, infinite loop.

---

Also, you think that your `getchar` is wrong, but your printf hasn't got any argument to display.

```
operand=getchar();
printf("operand=%c");
```

Should have been :

```
operand=getchar();
printf("operand=%c", operand);
```

Comment: No that didnt fix the problem

Comment: Oh, your `do {} while` statement is always true too. But this time, it must exist when you have `operand` equals to `+`, `-`, `*` or `/`.    So it would be `while(operand=='+' || operand=='-' || operand=='*' || operand=='/');`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code fixed

```
struct complex { float Rez, Imz; }; 

int main( )
{
    char operand;
struct complex z1, z2;
printf("give the Real part of the first imaginary number z1:\n");
scanf( "%f", &z1.Rez ); 
printf("give the Imaginary part of the first imaginary number z1: \n");
scanf( "%f", &z1.Imz );     
printf("give the Real part of the second imaginary number z2: \n");
scanf( "%f", &z2.Rez ); 
printf("give the Imaginary part of the second imaginary number z2: \n");
scanf( "%f", &z2.Imz ); 
do
{
    printf("Give + for ADD\nGive * for MULTIPLICATION\nGive - for SUBTRACTION\nGive / for DIVISION\n");
    operand=getchar();
    if (operand!='+' || operand!='-' || operand!='*' || operand!='/')
        printf("Wrong operation.Try again.\n");
}while(operand=='+' || operand=='-' || operand=='*' || operand=='/');

if(operand=='+')
{
    printf("\nYou have chosen to add the numbers.\nThe result of the ADD is the inaginary number\n imz=(%f+%f) +(%f+%f)",z1.Rez,z2.Rez,z1.Imz,z2.Imz);  
}
if(operand=='-')
{

}
if(operand=='*')
{

}
if(operand=='/')
{

}
system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That will always print `Wrong operation.Try again.`, whatever the `operand` value is, but at least the loop exits at some point. +1 for you.

Answer (score -1):

I change the do while in this and it doesnt ask me to put a char it just ends it seems that its ignoring getchar dont know why

```
do 
{ 
    printf("Give + for ADD\nGive * for MULTIPLICATION\nGive - for SUBTRACTION\nGive / for DIVISION\n"); 
    operand=getchar(); 
}
while(operand=='+' );
```

Comment: Try without a loop then, look if the processor really go through the instructions.

Comment: Then it has something to do with the buffer... Take a look at this question : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573457/how-to-flush-the-console-buffer)

Comment: il try what they are saying there thanks a lot for your time my friend

Comment: Nothing the same problem again i cant run any exercise in Dev c whats wrong :( !!